# VBA Error due to non anglo-saxon punctuation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to apply a function to a cell, but I'm not able to insert my variable in the string due to my punctuation settings (decimals are seperated by comma and not point). I set up a few examples below:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim X As Double
    Dim strFormula As String

    X = 0.5

    strFormula = "=A1+" & X
    Cells(2, 1) = strFormula
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    Dim X As Double
    Dim strFormula As String

    strFormula = "=B1+0.5"

    Cells(2, 2) = strFormula
End Sub

Sub Test3()
    Dim X As Double
    Dim strFormula As String

    strFormula = "=C1+0,5"

    Cells(2, 3) = strFormula
End Sub
```

The only sub that works is Test2, the others give me an object-defined error. All variables in the local window are defined using comma as the decimal separator, so X in Test1 in is defined as 0,5 and the string as "=A1+0,5" (same as Test3), which excel is not able to recognize.

Does anyone know how to get around this without changing the punctuation settings?

**EDIT:** I tried implementing the following code, but it only changes the settings in the sheets and not in the VBA code

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Application
        .DecimalSeparator = "."
        .ThousandsSeparator = ","
        .UseSystemSeparators = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How about `strFormula = "=A1+" & Replace(X, Application.DecimalSeparator, ".")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
Cells(2, 3).Formula = strFormula
```

`Range.Formula` expects a period separator, and is what you would usually use in VBA code.

`Range.FormulaLocal` is similar but expects a formula in the user's language, so would only normally be used to set a Formula that comes from user input.

Comment: Your code example says `.Formula`, but your explanation says `.FormulaLocal`. Thought I would give you the chance to check and fix it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much, FormulaLocal works! I knew the Formul code, but I didnt realize that there was a local version of it as well.

Comment: Just to add a little, the variables in VBA are written as "X = 0.5", you cant use commad as a decimal seperator,  but it is still read as "X = 0,5"